# What's the use for an offline version of Delicious?

Tags: delicious, offline

previous.delicious.com:

> This version of the Delicious website will be shutdown by April 2014.
>   We encourage users to switch to the new Delicious site at
>   http://delicious.com, which features a responsive design for mobile
>   and tablet users, offline access, faster loading, and more.

Delicious is mainly a collection of links. What's the use for an offline version of Delicious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bookmark more than just pages that are live on the World Wide Web.

- Intranet pages
- Email addresses
- Local files

I also expect offline access would be useful if you can reach the Web but can't reach Delicious.